# Parameter 1 of constructor in service.BuildingService required a bean of type 'persistence.BuildingDboMapper' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I’m learning Spring boot, now I am working on spring boot application. While running the application it fails. Maybe you have any ideas and see where I am wrong or miss something and can help solve my problem.

using Eclipse IDE

this is a gradle project

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in service.BuildingService required a bean of type 'persistence.BuildingDboMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'persistence.BuildingDboMapper' in your configuration.
```

**BuildingService class**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BuildingService {

    
    private final BuildingRepository buildingRepository;
    private final BuildingDboMapper buildingDboMapper;

    public List<Building> findAll() {
        return buildingRepository.findAll().stream().map(buildingDboMapper::map).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Building findBuildingById(Long id) {
        return buildingDboMapper.map(buildingRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow());
    }

    public void save(Building building) {
    }
}
```

**BuildingDboMapper interface**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface BuildingDboMapper {
    
    Building map(BuildingDbo dbo);

    BuildingDbo map(Building building);
}
```

**Main class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    private final BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void fillDb() {
        BuildingDbo building0 = new BuildingDbo().setId(1L).setName("Big Building").setAddress("Highway 420").setIndex("NO600").setEnergyUnits(400).setEnergyUnitMax(500).setSectorCode("CX60");
        BuildingDbo building1 = new BuildingDbo().setId(2L).setName("Small Building").setAddress("Highway 1200").setIndex("NO90000").setEnergyUnits(20).setEnergyUnitMax(100).setSectorCode("CX12");

        buildingRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(building0, building1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your main Spring Boot class?

Comment: @João Dias - main Spring Boot class added

Answer (score 0):

Try to do mvn clean install. Mapstruct generates the implementation class at compile time. Also make sure your pom.xml (or build.gradle) looks something like this:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                   -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: **build.gradle** dependencies looks like that:
`dependencies {
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.5.5'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.5.5'
implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.4.2.Final'
implementation group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '2.0.2'
...`

Comment: `...
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-processor', version: '1.4.2.Final'
runtimeOnly group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
} `

Comment: Did you compile the project?

Comment: Gradle build successfully - I understand that project compiled. 

But APPLICATION FAILED TO START